# Windows 10, sound enhancement wont turn off

Tags: audio, windows-10

Ever since I upgraded to win 10 I can't turn off sound enhancement and that wouldn't be a problem if it didn't sound terrible.

If I go to speaker properties and check the "disable all sound effects" option I'll get normal sound again, but that would only affect the currently playing video. I suppose it resets itself automatically because I have to un-check and check (again) the disable option.

Is there any way that I can permanently disable windows's sound enhancement?

*I tried updating the realtek sound driver, but this didn't change anything, so I believe it's a windows problem.*

Comment: I struggled with the realtek drivers on one machine. Uninstall/reinstall using the ones from realtek.tw eventually fixed it. No amount of installing over the old one would.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm unsure of which driver to download, would you care to share a link? I've already tried to download one, but it wouldn't start the download...

Comment: sorry, it's realtek.com.tw - this is the full link, but it will make you click an agreement to get there - http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false , get the latest  'blue' one for 32 or 64 bit